# Openui5 Grid-table toolbar not compact.

Tags: sapui5

When running the downloaded examples of Tables, eg [This sample](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Menus/preview),
The Toolbar and toolbar icon-buttons do not render correctly.

Example: First is what is in the sample, second is how it's rendered in in the docs.

[image: What's in the downloaded example]

[image: What's on the sample-page]

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I notice that the working example's toolbar has the following rule applied to its toolbar:

```
.sapUiSizeCompact .sapMTB {
height: 2rem;}
```

Looks as if you need to include the following into either the table or mvc:view element in your view.

```
class=".sapUiSizeCompact"
```

More can be read about the class [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/13/e6f3bfc54c4bd7952403e20ff447e7/frameset.htm).